# How to install K3s without ServiceLB

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, k3s, k3sup

I'm trying to install k3s by using k3sup. I want also to use kube-vip instead of ServiceLB.

For this reason, I first tried to install k3s on the control node with the following command:

```bash
k3sup install --k3s-channel stable --ip $CTRL_IP --user myuser --cluster --k3s-extra-args "--no-deploy traefik --no-deploy servicelb"
```

but it fails:

```
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s
Job for k3s.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status k3s.service" and "journalctl -xeu k3s.service" for details.
Error: error received processing command: Process exited with status 1
```

Systemctl does not give any other useful information.

If I keep ServiceLB, K3s is correctly installed:

```bash
k3sup install --k3s-channel stable --ip $CTRL_IP --user myuser --cluster
```

All the guides I found do not mention any problem on that. How can I install k3s without servicelb?

> Note: I tried also to use `--no-extras` instead of `--k3s-extra-args "--no-deploy traefik --no-deploy servicelb"`, but it did not work.

Comment: Refer this [document](https://devopstales.github.io/kubernetes/k3s-etcd-kube-vip/) to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved by keeping traefik installation. The `extra` args were changed as follows:

```
--k3s-extra-args "--no-deploy servicelb"
```